# Sklearn SVM question classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, dataset, text-classification

So, I have found that there are many ways to classify words with sklearn's SVM algorithm. But I want to classify questions by taxonomy, as shown in the following dataset:

[image]

The goal of this task is to predict the taxonomy given the pdf file / string (question).
The questions are the following:

- How can I modify the below code to train a question-based classification model?
- How can I train a question classification model with SVM?

For this task, I have used the following Python libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import model_selection, naive_bayes, svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

Here, I have split the dataset into train and test sets.

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = 
model_selection.train_test_split(Corpus['question'],Corpus['taxonomy'],test_size=0.3)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()
Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)
```

I have used TF IDF transformer (TfidfTransformer) in sklearn library like this

```
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(Corpus['question'])
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)
```

But this will break down questions into words for each question.
The following code was used to make a word classifier to predict the taxonomy from words

```
SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto')
SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf,Train_Y)
# predict the labels on validation dataset
predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by questions classifier, predict which sentences are questions. Maybe if it has ? at the end, it's a question

Comment: @DirkNachbar  - No.. These all are questions. So I just want to predict the taxonomy (remember, understand, apply) to a given question (question string).

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is asking how to model the following problem: predicting question taxonomy, given the question.

The first thing that leaps into my mind is to use an encoder-decoder architecture.
For this, you would use an encoder to encode the question as a sequence of words/tokens. Here we could use a sequential model, such as an RNN or LSTM. This encoder then encodes the question into "hidden representation".

 Then the hidden representation is decoded, using a normal feedforward NN with a final 3-node softmax layer, which creates a probability distribution over question taxonomies.

For the input, you would convert the tokens into word embeddings and then feed them in one-by-one for each question. For the output, you would just obtain the index with the highest probability as the class label.

An SVM is a good idea, however this treats the question as a bag of words (i.e. word order does not matter). So any old random question such as "how what learn learn this that" (even though hugely incoherent") can still be classified.